# Two way databinding EditText

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, two-way-binding

I'm trying to get the onTextChange from Edit text with databinding inside ViewModel class !

I want to achieve something like this :

```
@BindingAdapter("imageUrl")
fun ImageView.bindImage( imgUrl: String?) {
        imgUrl?.let {
            val imgUri = imgUrl.toUri().buildUpon().scheme("https").build()
            Glide.with(this.context)
                .load(imgUri)
                .apply(
                    RequestOptions()
                        .error(R.drawable.ic_broken_image)
                )
                .into(this)

    }
}
```

But I want it inside viewmodel .. so the user type 'a' for example .. 'a' delivered to viewmodel by the databinding .
What can I do?

I tried to but BindingAdapter inside the viewModel but didnt work.

Comment: I think you should check this out: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/two-way

Comment: I tried it but not work with my case !